# Build regex for displayname

Tags: regex

how I can build a Regex that will bring me as first Group

Mustermann
filiale01

and second Group

"M" from Max after Comma.

This are my fields:
Copy Code

```
Mustermann, Max

filiale01
```

My result should be:
Copy Code

```
MustermannM 

filiale01
```

My goal ist to build this strings together with $1$2

What I have tried:

I have tried this, but with this regex I didnt get the filiale01 as Group1.

Copy Code

```
([A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]{1,}),{1}\s([A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]{1})
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: You can prepend an anchor and make the second part optional `^([A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+)(?:,\s([A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]))?` https://regex101.com/r/GkbQKK/1

Answer (score 0):

You can make the second part optional, but to prevent partial matches you can prepend an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string.

Note that you can omit `{1}` from the pattern and that `{1,}` can also be written as `+`

```
^([A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]+)(?:,\s([A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]))?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GkbQKK/1/)